Error debug mode
Quiero usar este widget para que al pesarle un código de país y escribir un código postal, el usuario presione el botón de validar para que obtenga una localización y pues por el momento lo hice asi de rápido para mostrar la respuesta que me da, pero al implementar el código así, pues el debug mode se me cierra y no puedo volver a levantar mi aplicación. Sospecho que no estoy haciendo bien el uso de la asincronía y por eso la aplicación se cierra.
adjunto código provider:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:fireclub/features/profile/domain/entities/localization_cp.dart';
import 'package:fireclub/features/profile/presentation/providers/envia/envia_repository_provider.dart';

final localizationCpProvider = StateNotifierProvider<LocalizationCpNotifier, Map<String, List<LocalizationCpEntity>>>((ref) {
  final enviaRepository = ref.watch(enviaRepositoryProvider);
  return LocalizationCpNotifier(getLocalization: enviaRepository.getLocalizationByCp);
});

typedef GetLocalizationCpCallback = Future<List<LocalizationCpEntity>> Function(String countryCode, String cp);

class LocalizationCpNotifier extends StateNotifier<Map<String, List<LocalizationCpEntity>>> {
  final GetLocalizationCpCallback getLocalization;

  LocalizationCpNotifier({required this.getLocalization}) : super({});

  Future<List<LocalizationCpEntity>> loadLocalization(String countryCode, String cp) async {
    final key = '$countryCode-$cp';

    final localizations = await getLocalization(countryCode, cp);

    state = { ...state, key: localizations };

    return localizations;
  }
}


y aquí esta el codigo del widget donde implemento esto:
import 'package:fireclub/features/profile/presentation/providers/envia/country_provider.dart';
import 'package:fireclub/features/profile/presentation/providers/envia/localization_cp_provider.dart';
import 'package:fireclub/features/shared/widgets/custom_text_form_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


final inputValueProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');

class CityValidationField extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CityValidationField({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final color = Colors.grey.shade300;
    final inputValue = ref.watch(inputValueProvider);

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: CustomTextFormField(
            color: color,
            label: 'Postal Code / City',
            hint: 'Enter postal code or city',
            onChanged: (value) {
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 8),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: inputValue.isNotEmpty
              ? () async {
                  final selectedCountry = ref.read(selectedCountryProvider) ?? 'MX';
                  try {
                    final localizations = await ref.read(localizationCpProvider.notifier)
                        .loadLocalization(selectedCountry, inputValue);
                    print('Localizaciones obtenidas: $localizations');
                  } catch (e) {
                    print('Error al cargar localizaciones: $e');
                  }
                }
              : null,
          child: const Text('Validar'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


